# delete files from specific folders using shell script

Tags: find

I am using
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.6 (Tikanga). I wrote one shell script to delete files from specific folders.

```
find /app/psoft/pscfg/appserv/prcs/ABC/LOGS -type f -mtime +45  -exec ls {} \; >> "/app/Custom_Del_logs/prcslogs_`date  +%Y%m%d_%H%M`.log"

find /app/psoft/pscfg/appserv/prcs/ABC/LOGS -type f -mtime +45  -exec rm {} \;
```

the above script first list out all the files in mentioned log file which exceeds 45 days and then it will removed the files.
But the requirement is the list out files should be with date. so that we can recognize easily.

Comment: Just add a '-l' to the ls?

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

```
$ dir=/app/psoft/pscfg/appserv/prcs/ABC/LOGS

$ outdir=/app/Custom_Del_logs

$ find $dir -type f -mtime +45 -ls >> ${outdir}/prcslogs_$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M).log
```

Comment: thanks but i need the files only with date not with permission and all.

Comment: @Mannaji then please [edit] your question and show us your desired output.

Answer (score -1):

You may substitute the command ‍‍`ls` with `stat -c "%n %y"` , then you will get only last modify date info